# Not differentiable at zero but it square is differentiable at zero?

Tags: real-analysis

I need to check this because Im not completely sure if is fine or not.

The function $f(x)=|x|$ is not differentiable at zero but if we re-write

$$f(x)=|x|=\begin{cases}x,&\text{if }x\ge 0\\-x,&\text{if }x< 0\end{cases}$$

but we can see that

$$f(x)^2=|x|^2=\begin{cases}x^2,&\text{if }x\ge 0\\(-x)^2,&\text{if }x< 0\end{cases}=x^2$$

Then we have that $f(x)$ is not differentiable at zero but $f(x)^2$ is differentiable at zero. The problem that I see here comes from the definition of product rule

$$(fg)'(x)=f'(x)g(x)+g'(x)f(x)$$

then it seem that exist a contradiction because $f'(x)$ is not defined at zero.

My question, what happen here? I did some mistake? Please show me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Product rule (or chain rule, depend on how you are seeing the differentiation of $f^2$) says that *if each one is differentiable, then the product is* (resp. if the function is differentiable, then $f^2$) is. The converse need not hold.

Comment: Oh, I see. One little question: then the same thing happen with the algebraic rules for limits, by example $\lim (f+g)=\lim f+\lim g$?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 5):

The product rule applies when the factors are differentiable. But it can happen that the product is differentiable when the factors are not. A simpler example would be to pick one of the factors to be zero.

Answer (score 1):

That's an excellent counterexample to the converse of the product rule, which just states that if each factor is differentiable then the product is differentiable.